# how to get a value of href and make it scroll to an anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm trying to make my navigation scrollable using jquery, but for some reason, it isn't working. I tried a bunch of solutions but neither seems to be working.

My code:

**HTML:**

```
<nav class="column column-12 navigation nav">
    <ul>
        <li class="active onee"><a href="#home" class="scrollable">Home</a></li>
        <li class="onee"><a href="#portfolio" class="scrollable">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li class="onee"><a href="#about" class="scrollable">About</a></li>
        <li class="onee"><a href="#contact" class="scrollable">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

and all my sections have the same class as anchor `href`.

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".nav li").click(function() {
        $(".nav li").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });

    var $clicked = $("a")
        .attr("href")
        .split("#")
        .val();
        $("a").click(function() {
            /*$(this).find('a').attr('href').split("#");*/
            var url = $(this).attr("href");
            $("body").animate({
                /*scrollTop: $( '.' + $kazkas).offset().top}, 1000);*/
                scrollTop: $("." + url.split("#")).offset().top},1000);
        });
});
```

Here I'm trying to get the value of clicked anchor tag and use it to scroll my body just by getting rid of # and adding '.' so targeting my section class name. Unfortunately, doesn't work.

Full code can be found on my codepen: http://codepen.io/Limpuls/pen/YGdmkW

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Split, it will convert into array. Lets say,

```
var url = "#home";
```

so after split with url.split("#")

```
var arr = url.split("#");
//  arr[0] = ''
//  arr[1] = "home"
```

so if you don't want to assign it to variable then you can directly use like below

```
url.split("#")[1]
```

Also you need to prevent  default anchor tag event. to do that,

```
 $("a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

   // your code

 });
```

Comment: It works now, but it doesn't scrool smoothly, just jumps. Other thing is that it only scrolls to section that has id, not class. I wonder why it doesn't work with classes if I to add "." to a href value and it works with id's if I get rid of "#" with split("#").

Comment: still jumps. But now at least working :D What I'm missing for a smooth scroll? Pen: http://codepen.io/Limpuls/pen/YGdmkW